# How to bind the sub-property of an item in a listView?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, 2-way-object-databinding

I am stuck while trying to bind a property to another property.
The 2 properties are:

- in a richTextBox, the 'Content' dependency property
- in a listView, the selectedItem is a Book, and the selected book has a string property named "End".

I have to use 2 converters to transform the Content to string and the string to Content, so I can't use the TwoWay binding mode.

With this code:

```
<controls:RichEditControl
    x:Name="richEditControl1"
    BarManager="{Binding ElementName=barManager1, Mode=OneTime}"
    HorizontalRulerVisibility="Collapsed"
    VerticalRulerVisibility="Collapsed"
    Content="{Binding ElementName=listBoxBooks, Path=SelectedItem.End, Converter={StaticResource PlainContentConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

there should be half of the binding, but I can't figure out how to implement the second half, I mean from listView -> (Book)selectedItem -> End to the Content property.

I tried something like this:

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding("Content");
myBinding.Source = richEditControl1;
myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
listBoxBooks.SetBinding(ListView.SelectedItemProperty, myBinding);
```

but this is wrong as I don't want to bind the entire SelectedItemProperty but only its 'End' property. (the selectedItem is a 'Book' class).

thank you.

EDIT1
I changed the code-behind following the advice given in commentary, but without any success.
the code is:

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding("End");
myBinding.Source = (Book)listBoxBooks.SelectedItem;
myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
richEditControl1.SetBinding(RichEditControl.ContentProperty, myBinding);
```

(in fact it invert the direction of the binding, but I think the first direction was wrong).

Comment: If I follow this correctly. You're trying to create your own property for binding on your custom control. Have you tried using a dependency property?

Comment: Never-mind, I see now you're trying to bind to a "ListBox" control.

Comment: I think if you can somehow set your binding source to the RichEditControl.SelectedItem (myBinding.Source = richEditControl1.SelectedItem;) you should be able to just update your binding to "Binding myBinding = new Binding("End");"

Comment: @B.Spangenberg : plz have a look at my edit

Answer (score 0):

After the update I think I understand what you are trying to do. So my understanding is that you have a list of books and on selection of a book you just want to update your custom control to reflect.

If there is no specific reason for you binding via code, you could use the below technique.
( I made a quick demo on my end for example)

Step 1 : Setup XAML to bind directly to Listbox.SelectedItem.

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800">

<Window.Resources>
    <local:DummyConverter x:Key="DummyConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>


<Grid Margin="15">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListBox x:Name="MyListOfBooks" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BookCollection, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=End, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat='dddd, dd MMMM yyyy'}" Margin="30,0,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <!--Replace with custom control, make sure your custom control has a dependancy property for this binding-->
    <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Title, ElementName=MyListOfBooks, Converter={StaticResource DummyConverter}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="10"/>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Step 2: Here is my demo code to assist.

```
namespace TestWPF
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
      MainViewModel model;
      public MainWindow()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
          this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
      }

      private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
          model = new MainViewModel();
          model.Load();
          this.DataContext = model;
      }       
  }

  public class MainViewModel
  {
      public ObservableCollection<Book> BookCollection { get; set; }

      public void Load()
      {
          BookCollection = new ObservableCollection<Book>
          {
              new Book() { Title = "Book One", End = DateTime.Now },
              new Book() { Title = "Book Two", End = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10) },
              new Book() { Title = "Book Three", End = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2) }
          };
      }
  }

  public class Book : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
     private string title;
     private DateTime end;

     public string Title
     {
        get { return title; }
        set
        {
            title = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
     }
     public DateTime End
     {
         get { return end; }
         set
         {
            end = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
         }
      }

      public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
      {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   }


  public class DummyConverter : IValueConverter
  {
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        return string.Join("-", encoding.GetBytes((value as string) ?? string.Empty));
      }


      public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
          if (value == null)
              return null;

          string val = (value as string);

          var array = val.Split('-');
          Byte[] byteArray = new Byte[array.Length];
          for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
          {
              Byte.TryParse(array[i], out byte x);
            byteArray[i] = x;
          }

          return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteArray);
      }
 }
}
```

If you're still having trouble with the binding or If I misunderstood the issue, please let me know. Also provide the code for your custom control.

Comment: Updated it to support two way binding

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer, but I just found a solution : in fact, I did not tell you that I tried with a binding mode equal to TwoWay, I told you it wasn't possible. But I was wrong, a TwoWay is compatibvle with a converter as the converter contains two methods for each direction of conversion. It was possible, with this code :

```
Content="{Binding ElementName=listBoxBooks, Path=SelectedItem.End,Converter={StaticResource PlainToContentConverter},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

but the formatting was lost. I thought that was caused by the lack of the second converter (in the other direction) but as I just pointed out, I was wrong. The above code does not keep formatting because it is simply not saving it in plain text! Replacing the converter by an HtmlToContentConverter does the job!

thank you anyway for the time you spent!

Comment: Ah that's great news. I was actually working on a update for the converter issue before you posted. I updated my answer anyway. Good luck.